# Test mysql/PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The point of failure for my website is the database. I connect to it in a line included on all pages on the site that looks like this:

```
$GLOBALS['database'] = new PDO('mysql:mysql.host.address;dbname=db1', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
```

If the database has too many connections open, I get a fatal error. I'd like to do this:

```
header('Location: http://www.website.org/sorry.php', true, 302);
```

Is there a test that will, instead of giving a "too many errors" message, let me do that 302? Do I need to use a timer that's one second less than the timeout on mysql?

Comment: `try { new pdo } catch { handle error ... }`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: *I connect to it in a line included on all pages on the site* how many pages do you have? and I hope you mean really pages but not on every php script?

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
try{
$GLOBALS['database'] = new PDO('mysql:mysql.host.address;dbname=db1', 'USER', 'PASSWORD',
array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}catch(PDOException $ex){
header('Location: http://www.website.org/sorry.php', true, 302);

}
```